# Android/IOS mobile keyboard overlapping form's fields

Tags: mobile, soft-keyboard

[In first picture mobile keyboard not opened yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Mq7.jpg)

[In second picture when i tap on last input field the mobile keyboard overlap the whole field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAebs.jpg)

Please help me in this, i have searched already but didn't found a working solution for this.

Comment: Please specify what platform you are using? answer depends on what u are using? ASFAIK for ios check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: IDK about android but for iOS you can fix this issue using [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) which automatically changes frames of fields to always keep them above keyboard when they become first responder

Comment: Extremely sorry i didn't mentioned that it's a web base form not a app. and i m checking it on mobile browser and chrome.